# Is something wrong with this solution for $\sin 2x = \sin x$?

Tags: trigonometry

I have this question. What are the solutions for $$ 
\sin 2x = \sin x;  \\ 0 \le x < 2 \pi $$

My method:

$$ \sin 2x - \sin x = 0 $$
I apply the formula $$  \sin a - \sin b = 2\sin \left(\frac{a-b}{2} \right) \cos\left(\frac{a+b}{2} \right)$$
So:

$$ 2\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \cos\left(\frac{3x}{2}\right) = 0 $$
$$ \sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{3x}{2}\right) = 0 $$
Here one of the factors has to be $0$,
$$ \sin x = 0 \ \Rightarrow \  x = 0  \ or \ x = \pi $$
$$ \sin\left(\frac{x}{2}'\right) = 0 \ \Rightarrow \  x = 0  ;\  x \text{ can't be } \pi \text{ because of its range} $$

$$ \cos x = 0 \ \Rightarrow \  x = \frac{\pi}{2} \text{ or } \ x = \frac{3\pi}{2} $$
$$ \cos\left(\frac{3x}{2}\right) = 0 => x =  \frac{\pi}{3} \text{ or } x = \pi $$

So the solutions are : $$ 0, \pi,  \frac{\pi}{3} $$

I have seen other methods to solve this, so please don't post them. I'm really interested what's wrong with this one.

Comment: I do not understand how $\pi$ can be an answer when you already mentioned it *out of domain*

Comment: Except for the fact that $\pi$ isn't less than $\pi$, is something wrong? I think it's fine.

Comment: Besides $\pi$ being excluded as an answer, why do you think your answer is wrong?

Comment: I've edited the question, it was 2pi , sorry

Comment: I don't know why it's wrong. The solutions are not these.

Comment: What do you mean the solutions aren't those?  sin(pi) = sin(2pi) = 0.  sin(\pi/3) = sin(\2pi/3) = root(3)/2.  Geometrically eyeballing these are the only such solutions.  Why do you say the solutions aren't those?

Comment: So if those are the solutions, what do the other methods claim are the solutions?

Comment: The solutions are: 0, pi/3, pi and 5pi/3

Comment: You restriction x to 0 and 2pi but you wrongly restricted 2x  and 3x/2 to the same range.  The range for 3x/2 is 0 to 3 pi so 3x/2 = 5pi/2 is a possible solution.

Comment: Why has the domain of the solution set been changed back and forth multiple times?  It was originally $0 \le x < \pi$, then changed to $0 \le x < 2\pi$, and now changed back again.  This is unacceptable editing behavior.  The statement of the problem must be made clearly, precisely, and **definitively**.  It should not be that difficult to accurately transcribe a problem like this.

Comment: I'm didn't edit it back again, I think a moderator did. IT IS 2PI

Comment: I don't know why he modifies the problem, as he would know the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong up to the reduction to
$$
\sin\frac{x}{2}\cos\frac{3x}{2}=0
$$
Then you have either
$$
\sin\frac{x}{2}=0
$$
that is, $x/2=k\pi$ and $x=2k\pi$, or
$$
\cos\frac{3x}{2}=0
$$
so
$$
\frac{3x}{2}=\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi
$$
and
$$
x=\frac{\pi}{3}+\frac{2k\pi}{3}
$$

Now let's examine the first set of solutions; you want to find the integers $k$ such that
$$
0\le 2k\pi<2\pi
$$
and this is only for $k=0$. For the second set of solutions,
$$
0\le\frac{\pi}{3}+\frac{2k\pi}{3}<2\pi
$$
becomes
$$
0\le 1+2k<6
$$
which gives $k\in\{0,1,2\}$.

Thus you find
$$
x\in\left\{0,\frac{\pi}{3},\pi,\frac{5\pi}{3}\right\}
$$

Comment: sinx = 0 requires x = 0 or x = 2pi (this cannot be, so excluded); cosx = 0 requires x = pi/2 or x = 3pi/2. What's wrong with just solving 0 = 3x/2, pi/2 = 3x/2 and 3pi/2 = 3x/2? How is that solution excluded and why

Comment: @BogdanPop Because it's $x$ that should be in the interval $[0,2\pi)$, not $3x/2$.

Comment: Where exactly i was assuming that in my steps?

Comment: @BogdanPop On the other hand, reducing the equation to $\sin x(2\cos x-1)=0$ is simpler.

Answer (score 4):

$$\sin(2x)=\sin(x)\implies 2\cos(x)\sin(x)=\sin(x).$$
The elements of the form $k\pi$ are solutions (notice that if you divide the equation by $\sin(x)$ with not paying attention to this condition, you will loose solutions). Suppose $x\neq k\pi$. Then,
$$2\cos(x)\sin(x)=\sin(x)\implies 2\cos(x)=1\implies \cos(x)=\frac{1}{2}\implies x\in \left\{\pm\frac{\pi}{3}+2k\pi\mid k\in\mathbb Z\right\}.$$

Finally the solution are given by
$$\{k\pi\mid k\in\mathbb Z\}\cup\left\{\pm\frac{\pi}{3}+2k\pi\mid k\in\mathbb Z\right\}.$$

I let you take the solutions in $[0,2\pi[$.

Answer (score 2):

$\sin A=0\implies A=n\pi$

$\cos B=0\implies B=(2m+1)\pi/2$

$m,n$ are arbitrary integers

Answer (score 1):

If we need to solve $$\sin \frac{x}{2} \cos \frac{3x}{2} = 0$$ for $0 \le x < 2\pi$, then the inequality condition is equivalent to $$0 \le x/2 < \pi,$$ and $$0 \le 3x/2 \le 3\pi.$$  Thus $\sin x/2 = 0$ admits only $x = 0$ in first interval; and in the second interval, we have solutions $$\frac{3x}{2} \in \left\{ \frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{3\pi}{2}, \frac{5\pi}{2} \right\},$$ as all of these are between $0$ and $3\pi$.  Consequently, the second factor admits the solutions $$x \in \left\{\frac{\pi}{3}, \pi, \frac{5\pi}{3} \right\}.$$ The complete solution set is therefore $$x \in \left\{0, \frac{\pi}{3}, \pi, \frac{5\pi}{3} \right\}$$ in the desired interval.

---

A plot of the curves $$\color{blue}{y = \sin 2x}, \quad \color{orange}{y = \sin x}, \quad \color{green}{y = \sin 2x - \sin x}$$ is shown below:

[image]

As you can see, the green curve intersects the $x$-axis at the claimed values (as well as at $2\pi$ but this was excluded by the condition $0 \le x < 2\pi$).  You can also visually see that the $x$-coordinates at which the blue and orange curves coincide (corresponding to the equality $\sin 2x = \sin x$) are also the $x$-coordinates at which the green curve intersects the $x$-axis.

Comment: You meant $0 \leq \frac{3x}{2} \color{red}{<} 3\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

In restricting $0 \le x < 2\pi$ you are were inadvertently also restricting $0 \le 2x < 2\pi$ which is not a stated restriction.

So $x = \pi$ **is** a solution as $\sin 2\pi$ *does* = $\sin \pi$ after all.

(Likewise $\sin 5\pi/3 = \sin 10\pi/3 = \sin 4\pi/3$).

So your restrictions are actually $0 \le 2x < 4\pi$ and for that matter $0 \le 3x/2 < 3\pi$.

So why did your answer not pick up $x = 5\pi/3$ as a potential answer.

As

Then as $\cos(3x/2) = 0$ is potential answer, $0 \le 3x/2 < 3\pi$, so  $3x/2 = \pi/2, 3\pi/2, 5\pi/2$ so $x = \pi/3, \pi, 5\pi/3$.

Answer (score 0):

Other people have already pointed out we can rewrite like this:
$$2\sin(t)\cos(t) = \sin(t)$$
Now what most other people have not done, is this to substitute $\sin(t)$ and $\cos(t)$ for $y$ and $x$ and rewrite the problem to an algebraic variety:
$$\cases{2yx - y = 0\\
x^2+y^2=0}$$

This particular one is really silly easy to factor ( compared to systems of polynomial equations in general ):

$$\cases{y(2x-1) = 0\\x^2+y^2=0}$$

So either $2x-1 = 0$ or $y=0$

We recognize these equations as lines in the plane. The solutions are where they intercept the unit circle. Now it will be an easy exercise to substitute back and find all solutions.